# Adding Firebase Post Overwrites All Other Posts Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have written code that correctly writes a single post to my Firebase database. The issue is that when I add another post it overwrites the post that was there previously. How can I add the posts to the existing array without overwriting?

```
  func postToFirebase(imgUrl: String) {
        let post: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [
            "caption": postDescription.text! as AnyObject,
            "imageUrl": imgUrl as AnyObject,
            "likes": 0 as AnyObject
        ]

        let firebasePost = DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.childByAutoId()
        firebasePost.setValue(post)
        let userPost = firebasePost.key

        print("Firebase Post: \(String(describing: firebasePost))")


        _ = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth,user) in
            if let user = user {
                let userId = user.uid
                print("USER: \(String(describing: userId))")
                let newPost = DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child("\(userId)").child("posts")
                //print("NEW POST: \(newPost.child)")
                newPost.setValue([userPost : true])

            }
        }

        postDescription.text = ""
        imageSelected = false
        newPostImage.image = UIImage(named: "icons8-camera-100")

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by making a minor change to how I was setting the value. It now looks like this:

```
let newPost = DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child("\(userId)").child("posts").child(userPost!)
newPost.setValue(true)
```