# Recommendations for Firebase database structure

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question about the best way to structure my Firebase database for my iOS app. The basic structure is that there are `users` and `posts`. The app will open and the `user` who is logged in will see all the `posts` that he/she has uploaded to the database (I may update this down the road so that users can see posts of `users` they follow). Is it better to have each `post` have a `userId` on it? Or is it better to have the an array of `posts` associated to each `user`?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can shard/partition the data so that you don't need to query a potentially very long list of that, that is always preferable with the realtime database.

So in your case, if you know that you want to show the user a list of their own posts as a starting point, it is a good idea to model that list in your database. You'd typically call this the user's feed or wall, depending on what your social network of choice is.

If you then later want to also show the posts of users they follow, you might want to store those posts in the user's wall. This type of data duplication may seem unnatural at first, but is quite common in NoSQL databases. In fact, this is the exact model that Firebase uses in its class [FireFeed example](https://firefeed.io/).

To learn more about NoSQL data modeling, see:

- [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).
- [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).
- [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ), which is about Firebase's newer Firestore database, but has great tips that apply to the Realtime Database too.

Comment: That makes sense and I believe the structure I have in my app matches that of Firefeed. However, I am running into an issue where when I add a new post under the user, it overwrites the rest of the posts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56808006/adding-firebase-post-overwrites-all-other-posts-swift. Any idea how to correct this?